# Linq Join multi key one side of key is null

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Trying to join two tables where part of the key on one side is nullable.  Getting "Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage", which I believe is related to the mismatched types in the key.

```
TableA.GroupJoin(TableB,
  a => new {a.IntKeyA, a.StringKeyA},
  b => new {b.NullIntKeyB, b.StringKeyB}
 (tabA, tabB) => new {tabA, tabB});
```

Tried to cast the type of the key in TableA

```
a => new (int?, string) {a.IntKeyA, a.StringKeyA}
```

or

```
a => (int?, string)(new  {a.IntKeyA, a.StringKeyA})
```

Tried to Coalesce the key in TableB, magic number 0 isn't great but would have worked in this scenario.

```
b => new {b.NullIntKeyB ?? 0, b.StringKeyB}
```

Tried GetValueOrDefault

```
b => new {b.NullIntKeyB.GetValueOrDefault(), b.StringKeyB}
```

I suppose I could probably define a class to hold the key but I don't really want to do that every time this issue comes up.

Comment: I don't think you understand how to use cast in C#. You need to cast the value in the anonymous type, not the object itself, e.g. `new { (int?)a.IntKeyA, a.StringKeyA }`.

Comment: Oh I forgot to list it, but I tried that and it doesn't work either.

"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, this seems to have worked, but I'm not going to mark it as the answer yet in hopes there's an easier way.

```
class ReportKey
{
    private int? IntKey { get; }
    private string StringKey { get; } = string.Empty;
   
    internal ReportKey(int? intKey, string stringKey)
    {
        IntKey = intKey;
        StringKey = stringKey;
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as ReportKey;
    
        if (item == null) return false;
    
        return this.IntKey == item.Intkey &&
           StringKey == item.StringKey;
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return $"{IntKey}{StringKey}".GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

...

```
TableA.GroupJoin(TableB,
    a => new ReportKey(a.IntKeyA, a.StringKeyA),
    b => new ReportKey(b.NullIntKeyB, b.StringKeyB),
   (tabA, tabB) => new {tabA, tabB});
```